# Leaving Company without notifying anyone

Tags: legal-terms, india, labor-law

What if the company is not paying me for the last two months, because of that I absconded(leaving the Company without notifying anyone) the company. So there is an issue I will face? I have another offer in my hand.

Comment: Laws vary around the world, so which jurisdiction (country, province, state, principality etc) does this relate to?

Comment: I'm talking about Indian jurisdiction.

Comment: Wouldn’t you need a relieving letter from your prior company before joining the new one?

Comment: As I said I have another company's offer and they are ok with it.